# Do I need to check if an object has a property?

Tags: javascript, object

Do I have to check if an object has a specific property when e.g. using a for-loop to access it like:

```
for(var i = 0; i<array.length< i++) {
  console.log(array1[i].propertyName)
}
```

If the objects stored in the array differ for some having the specific property and some don't. Should I check it first with `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` or does it return undefined anyway without any conflicts?

Comment: Accessing a missing property will return `undefined`, not `null`.

Comment: @VLAZ SO I can just leave it like that without any needs for further checks?
Wondering if performance issues may appear.

Comment: I don't know. Depends on what you want to do with it. If you *just* want the values and you're fine with `undefined`s, then it's OK. If you want to then try to call a method on the value from the property, you'd get an error. If you *don't* want to get the missing properties, then you'd need to do something different. It's hard to say.

Comment: @Orange it's up to you and it will depend of your implementation

Comment: I'm using it in an Vue application for rendering the properties in a list. Don't know if Vue has troubles with returning undefined or not.

Comment: You don't have to check, *unless* you're planning to use a child of the child. For instance `array[i].propertyName.childProperty` will result in an error if `array[i].propertyName` is undefined.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks, that makes it clear. If you'd write an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the property exists with a simple if statement. As VLAZ pointed out, a missing property will return `undefined` which in JavaScript is equivalent to false (ey). So you could do:

```
for(var i = 0; i<array.length< i++) {
  //Will return false if the property doesn't exist
  if(array1[i].properyName != undefined) {
    console.log(array1[i].propertyName)

  }
}
```

Comment: This will also filter out other falsy values like zero or empty strings.

Comment: True, I've edited my answer to be more specific